# SQL Merge - Update a table 1 if value is found in table 2

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to tables :

```
Table1
---------------------------
ID         VAL1
---------------------------
1          1
2          null
3          1


Table2
---------------------------
ID         VAL2
---------------------------
1          N
2          O
3          O
```

I want to update column VAL1 of Table1 with '0', if VAL2 of Table2 is equal to 'O'. (This two tables can be joined with the ID column).

So the expected result is :

```
    Table1
---------------------------
ID         VAL1
---------------------------
1          1
2          0
3          0
```

I've tried to do it with a MERGE but I get 0 records updated.. Here my code :

```
MERGE
INTO    Table1
USING   (
        SELECT  t1.ID AS T1ID, t2.ID AS T2ID
        FROM    Table1 t1
        JOIN    Table2 t2
        ON      trim(t1.ID)=trim(t2.ID)
        WHERE   t2.VAL2='O'
        )
ON      (T1ID = T2ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     VAL1='0';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the using statement this way, with a where clause in the update part.

```
MERGE
INTO    Table1 t1
USING   Table2 t2
 ON (t1.Id = t2.Id) -- use Trim if needed, but this would mean Id is a VARCHAR ?

WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE
 SET     t1.VAL1=0
 WHERE t2.VAL2 = 'O'
```

Or with an update statement

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET t1.Val1 = 0
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
              FROM Table2 t2
              WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id
              AND t2.VAL2 = 'O')
```

Comment: With the MERGE statement I get an error : "ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables". But with the second statement it's working fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use standard UPDATE:

```
UPDATE Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
SET Table1.VAL1 = 0
WHERE Table2.VAL2 = 'O'
```

**EDIT**
Without JOIN:

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET Table1.VAL1 = 0
WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID
AND Table2.VAL2 = 'O'
```

Comment: I've received an error : "SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword".
My two tables are not so simple, it was just for the illustration. I've read it's not possible to use a JOIN in a UPDATE on SqlDeveloper, I'm wrong ?

Comment: I've tried your statement without the JOIN but it's also not permitted in Oracle (http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php). But thank you anyway it's good to know.